# Split a Tikzpicture Across Two Pages

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, split, tikz-pic, figure-placement

Often enough, I run into the problem of a tikzpicture being too large to fit on the page where I would like it to be.

Consider the MWE (compiled with pdfLatex):

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=6.25in]{geometry}
\textwidth=4in \textheight=3.15in \voffset -7pt \evensidemargin=-10pt


\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}  
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\definecolor{Italiangreen}{RGB}{0,140,69}
\definecolor{Italianred}{RGB}{205,33,42}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=4pt,amplitude=2.5pt}
    } %
]
\node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.7,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
%pencildraw,
draw,fill=Italiangreen,text width=0.85\textwidth,inner sep=4mm]
{\begin{minipage}{3.42in} \small
\selectfont \textbf{\lipsum[16]} \vspace{5pt} \hfill \textbf{\emph{---L. Iipsum}} \end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

with the output:

[image]

QUESTION: Aesthetically speaking, what should be done here? Is it possible to have LaTeX "split" the picture so that it displays over two pages---thus eliminating the unsightly large gap on the first page? In cases where the picture is slightly oversized, enlarging the first page a little with the `\enlargethispage` command seems to work fine. So, I would like to know the optimal thing to do when the tikzpicture is quite large relative to the space available on the first page. Suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Is your actual tikzpicture such a box with text or is this just an example? If that's your actual picture, I would suggest to use the `tcolorbox` package which has an option to make boxes breakable.

Comment: If you just want to put text in a colored box which should break over pages, try a `breakable` [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz The actual picture(s) pretty much resemble what I have posted---a shadowed box containing words.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you for the information regarding `tcolorbox`.

Comment: @DDS ... then that's a clear case for tcolorbox :)

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thanks for the suggestion..

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Sounds like it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a `tcolorbox` instead of a `tikzpicture`. Tcolorboxes have an option to allow page breaks.

Here an easy example to get you started:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{Italiangreen}{RGB}{0,140,69}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,colback=Italiangreen,drop shadow=black,sharp corners]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you for this post; but is it possible to replicate the shadow effect in the tikzpicture?

Comment: @DDS You can customise basically everything in a tcolorbox. See the user manual for all the available options https://texdoc.org/serve/tcolorbox.pdf/0

Comment: Thank you for this answer.

Comment: @DDS You're welcome!